# Как работать с LiveData правильно?

Tags: android, kotlin, livedata

Уважаемые форумчане подскажите пожалуйста, почему не происходит вызова функции "onChanged"?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val liveData = DataController.getData()

    liveData?.observe(this, Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        fun onChanged(@Nullable value:String) {
            textView.text = value
        }
    });
}

fun refresh(view: View) {
    DataController.refresh()
}

object DataController {                                 //  это синглтон!
private val liveData = MutableLiveData<String>()

fun getData(): LiveData<String>? {
    return liveData
}

fun getCurrentDateTime(): Date {
    return Calendar.getInstance().time
}

fun refresh(){
    val date = getCurrentDateTime()
    val dateInString = date.toString()
    liveData.value = dateInString
}
```

Саму подписку вроде верно сделал, данные обновляю путём вызова: DataController.refresh()

Исходный код лежит здесь: https://github.com/genbachae/T_LiveData

или здесь: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wKZx_UZSJxk2PY3JMO0Csq_oJ9_WyU8W

Answer (score 0):

Подправил чуть Ваш код. Попробуйте:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val liveData = DataController.getData()

        liveData?.observe(this, object : Observer,
            androidx.lifecycle.Observer<String> {

            override  fun onChanged(@Nullable value: String) {
                textView.text = value
            }

            override fun update(o: Observable?, arg: Any?) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        })
    }

    fun refresh(view: View) {
        DataController.refresh()
    }

    object DataController {
        private val liveData = MutableLiveData<String>()

        fun getData(): LiveData<String>? {
            return liveData
        }

        fun getCurrentDateTime(): Date {
            return Calendar.getInstance().time
        }

        fun refresh() {
            val date = getCurrentDateTime()
            val dateInString = date.toString()
            liveData.value = dateInString
        }
    }
}
```

Из рекомендаций: переносите код в вопрос в таком виде как он у Вас есть, то есть со всеми скобками. Так  не придется тратить время на угадывание где она у Вас должна была стоять.